# Model.evaluate accuracy and keras console accuracy does not match with sklearn metrics

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I trained a model using inceptionV3 transfer learning with keras. After the training process calculated validation accuracy and loss with model.evaluate() function. the same accuracy was calculated with sklearn accuracy_score function. Both accuracy do not match.

```
data_gen=ImageDataGenerator(1./255)
train_datagen=data_gen.flow_from_directory('/directory/',target_size= 
(224,224),class_mode='categorical')
val_datagen=data_gen.flow_from_directory('/directory/',target_size= 
(224,224),class_mode='categorical')
test_datagen=data_gen.flow_from_directory('/directory/',target_size= 
(224,224),class_mode='categorical')
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
import os
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3

pre_trained_model=InceptionV3(include_top=False,input_shape=(224,224,3),weights=None)
local_weights_file="weights file"
pre_trained_model.load_weights(local_weights_file)
for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
 layer.trainable=False

last_layer=pre_trained_model.get_layer('mixed1')
last_output=last_layer.output
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
x=layers.Flatten()(last_output)
x=layers.Dense(1024,activation="relu")(x)
x=layers.Dense(1024,activation="relu")(x)
x=layers.Dense(2,activation="softmax")(x)
model=Model(pre_trained_model.input,x)
for layer in model.layers:
  layer.trainable=True
 model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics= 
 ['accuracy'])


history=model.fit(train_datagen,epochs=1,validation_data=val_datagen)
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py:720: 
UserWarning: This ImageDataGenerator specifies `featurewise_center`, but it hasn't been fit on any training data. Fit it first by calling `.fit(numpy_data)`.
  warnings.warn('This ImageDataGenerator specifies '
   2/4808 [..............................] - ETA: 3:53 - loss: 51.0154 - accuracy: 0.4375WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.0359s vs `on_train_batch_end` time: 0.0599s). Check your callbacks.
4808/4808 [==============================] - 496s 103ms/step - loss: 0.6041 - accuracy: 0.7569 - val_loss: 0.5383 - val_accuracy: 0.7454
```

Code:

```
model.evaluate(val_datagen)
```

Output:

```
1/601 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6641 - accuracy: 0.6875/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py:720: UserWarning: This ImageDataGenerator specifies `featurewise_center`, but it hasn't been fit on any training data. Fit it first by calling `.fit(numpy_data)`.
  warnings.warn('This ImageDataGenerator specifies '
601/601 [==============================] - 35s 58ms/step - loss: 0.5383 - accuracy: 0.7454
[0.5382987856864929, 0.7454498410224915]
```

Code:

```
y_pred=model.predict(val_datagen)
y_pred=np.argmax(y_pred,axis=1)
y_true=val_datagen.classes
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y_pred,y_true)
```

Output:

```
0.47836713468538744
```

My validation accuracy given by keras is 0.74, However sklearn metrics accuracy_score gives a different accuracy of 0.47. PLEASE HELP!

Any effort would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get the same accuracy if you run the final block multiple times?

Comment: Yes I get the same accuracy if i rerun the last block. It only changes after i rerun the model in which case the model.evaluate numbers also change. in any case the difference is quite high between both the accuracies.